# deployment success in cloudflare pages but 404 error when entering website

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma, cloudflare, vercel

Build Log

> 2023-08-17T06:46:46.128927Z   Cloning repository...
> 2023-08-17T06:46:47.000851Z   From https://github.com/lunwingkit/membersonly
> 2023-08-17T06:46:47.001638Z    * branch            cdaed25e6d1471b54a61022341d6a620bd892eb3 -> FETCH_HEAD
> 2023-08-17T06:46:47.001915Z
> 2023-08-17T06:46:47.074642Z   HEAD is now at cdaed25 no message
> 2023-08-17T06:46:47.075606Z
> 2023-08-17T06:46:47.190192Z
> 2023-08-17T06:46:47.222746Z   Success: Finished cloning repository files
> 2023-08-17T06:46:47.870478Z   Detected the following tools from environment: npm@9.5.1, nodejs@18.16.1
> 2023-08-17T06:46:47.871588Z   Installing project dependencies: npm clean-install --progress=false
> 2023-08-17T06:46:57.888375Z   npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
> 2023-08-17T06:47:21.882146Z
> 2023-08-17T06:47:21.882888Z   added 1007 packages, and audited 1008 packages in 33s
> 2023-08-17T06:47:21.883093Z
> 2023-08-17T06:47:21.883245Z   135 packages are looking for funding
> 2023-08-17T06:47:21.883378Z     run `npm fund` for details
> 2023-08-17T06:47:21.884905Z
> 2023-08-17T06:47:21.885228Z   found 0 vulnerabilities
> 2023-08-17T06:47:21.917695Z   Executing user command: npx @cloudflare/next-on-pages@1
> 2023-08-17T06:47:24.353792Z   npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: @cloudflare/next-on-pages@1.5.1
> 2023-08-17T06:47:39.006419Z   npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-inject@3.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-inject.
> 2023-08-17T06:47:39.457864Z   npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
> 2023-08-17T06:47:40.201495Z   npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
> 2023-08-17T06:47:41.06851Z    npm WARN deprecated vm2@3.9.19: The library contains critical security issues and should not be used for production! The maintenance of the project has been discontinued. Consider migrating your code to isolated-vm.
> 2023-08-17T06:47:46.938104Z   ⚡️ @cloudflare/next-on-pages CLI v.1.5.1
> 2023-08-17T06:47:46.941358Z   ⚡️ Detected Package Manager: npm
> 2023-08-17T06:47:46.941725Z   ⚡️ Preparing project...
> 2023-08-17T06:47:46.943789Z   ⚡️ Project is ready
> 2023-08-17T06:47:46.944063Z   ⚡️ Building project...
> 2023-08-17T06:47:49.014965Z   ▲  npm
> 2023-08-17T06:47:49.015808Z   ▲  WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: vercel@31.4.0
> 2023-08-17T06:47:53.579471Z   ▲  Vercel CLI 31.4.0
> 2023-08-17T06:47:53.912599Z   ▲  Installing dependencies...
> 2023-08-17T06:47:56.553702Z   ▲  up to date in 2s
> 2023-08-17T06:47:56.554382Z   ▲  135 packages are looking for funding
> 2023-08-17T06:47:56.554625Z   ▲  run `npm fund` for details
> 2023-08-17T06:47:56.56865Z    ▲  Detected Next.js version: 13.4.13
> 2023-08-17T06:47:56.57576Z    ▲  Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
> 2023-08-17T06:47:56.576531Z   ▲  Running "npm run build"
> 2023-08-17T06:47:57.514908Z   ▲  > client@0.1.0 build
> 2023-08-17T06:47:57.515328Z   ▲  > next build
> 2023-08-17T06:47:58.104417Z   ▲  - info Loaded env from /opt/buildhome/repo/.env
> 2023-08-17T06:47:58.26768Z    ▲  Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
> 2023-08-17T06:47:58.268281Z   ▲  This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
> 2023-08-17T06:47:58.26864Z    ▲  You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
> 2023-08-17T06:47:58.268932Z   ▲  https://nextjs.org/telemetry
> 2023-08-17T06:47:58.391256Z   ▲  - info Creating an optimized production build...
> 2023-08-17T06:48:19.460476Z   ▲  - info Compiled successfully
> 2023-08-17T06:48:19.461413Z   ▲  - info Linting and checking validity of types...
> 2023-08-17T06:48:24.851456Z   ▲  - info Collecting page data...
> 2023-08-17T06:48:36.557059Z   ▲  - info Generating static pages (0/15)
> 2023-08-17T06:48:36.626966Z   ▲  - info Generating static pages (3/15)
> 2023-08-17T06:48:36.9846Z ▲  - info Generating static pages (7/15)
> 2023-08-17T06:48:37.104863Z   ▲  - info Generating static pages (11/15)
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.355415Z   ▲  - info Generating static pages (15/15)
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.882133Z   ▲  - info Finalizing page optimization...
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.888337Z   ▲
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.904981Z   ▲  Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.905342Z   ▲  ┌ ○ /                                      153 B          78.6 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.90557Z    ▲  ├ ○ /about                                 153 B          78.6 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.905741Z   ▲  ├ ○ /api                                   0 B                0 B
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.905922Z   ▲  ├ ○ /api/deleteAllData                     0 B                0 B
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.906078Z   ▲  ├ ○ /api/fetchAllData                      0 B                0 B
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.90622Z    ▲  ├ λ /api/importAllData                     0 B                0 B
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.906369Z   ▲  ├ ○ /bbs                                   152 B          78.6 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.906584Z   ▲  ├ ○ /checkout                              133 kB          390 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.906736Z   ▲  ├ ○ /contact                               153 B          78.6 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.906896Z   ▲  ├ ○ /event                                 154 B          78.6 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.907034Z   ▲  ├ ○ /favicon.ico                           0 B                0 B
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.907177Z   ▲  ├ ○ /reservation                           719 B           247 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.907316Z   ▲  └ ○ /reservation/reservationCalendar       679 B           233 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.907462Z   ▲  + First Load JS shared by all              78.5 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.907609Z   ▲  ├ chunks/596-4ccbe7e27d444f62.js         26 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.907745Z   ▲  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-a6a51877aa8a0ab8.js    50.5 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.907883Z   ▲  ├ chunks/main-app-46167771b63b011d.js    219 B
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.908017Z   ▲  └ chunks/webpack-64f9ff1f27cd61ab.js     1.71 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.908143Z   ▲
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.908267Z   ▲  Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.908426Z   ▲  ─ ○ /404                                   183 B          75.9 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.908563Z   ▲  + First Load JS shared by all              75.7 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.908707Z   ▲  ├ chunks/framework-43665103d101a22d.js   45.1 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.908852Z   ▲  ├ chunks/main-a95576b23b9828d5.js        28.7 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.908983Z   ▲  ├ chunks/pages/_app-6b79a29ad0d63b21.js  199 B
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.909113Z   ▲  └ chunks/webpack-64f9ff1f27cd61ab.js     1.71 kB
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.909263Z   ▲  λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
> 2023-08-17T06:48:42.909428Z   ▲  ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
> 2023-08-17T06:48:44.909692Z   ▲  Traced Next.js server files in: 1.785s
> 2023-08-17T06:48:54.629409Z   ▲  Created all serverless functions in: 9.718s
> 2023-08-17T06:48:54.64262Z    ▲  Collected static files (public/, static/, .next/static): 8.895ms
> 2023-08-17T06:48:56.125917Z   ▲  Build Completed in .vercel/output [1m]
> 2023-08-17T06:48:56.2497Z ⚡️ Completed `npx vercel build`.
> 2023-08-17T06:48:56.292813Z   ⚡️ **Watch mode unexpected error: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, copyfile '/opt/buildhome/repo/.vercel/output/functions/api.prerender-fallback.body' -> '/opt/buildhome/repo/.vercel/output/static/api'**
> 2023-08-17T06:48:56.350382Z   Finished
> 2023-08-17T06:48:56.351172Z   Note: No functions dir at /functions found. Skipping.
> 2023-08-17T06:48:56.351418Z   Validating asset output directory
> 2023-08-17T06:48:57.407572Z   Deploying your site to Cloudflare's global network...
> 2023-08-17T06:49:00.022098Z   Uploading... (33/41)
> 2023-08-17T06:49:00.593145Z   Uploading... (36/41)
> 2023-08-17T06:49:00.594445Z   Uploading... (38/41)
> 2023-08-17T06:49:00.653938Z   Uploading... (41/41)
> 2023-08-17T06:49:00.654407Z   ✨ Success! Uploaded 8 files (33 already uploaded) (1.15 sec)
> 2023-08-17T06:49:00.654633Z
> 2023-08-17T06:49:01.037814Z   ✨ Upload complete!
> 2023-08-17T06:49:02.972514Z   Success: Assets published!
> 2023-08-17T06:49:03.723524Z   Success: Your site was deployed!

Build Settings

> Build command:
>
> npx @cloudflare/next-on-pages@1
>
> Build output directory:
>
> /.vercel/output/static
>
> Build system version:
>
> 2 (latest)
>
> Root directory:
>
> /client
>
> Environment variables:

I am building a next.js project with app routing and the error occurs after the 3 routes (route.ts) are added in /api ( src/app/api/deleteAllData, src/app/api/fetchAllData, src/app/api/importAllData)

tried changing the output directory to /.next
or build command to npx run build but all failed with other error, also I built the exact same project directly on vercel and it worked smoothly

Comment: Is your repository open source? If yes, could you share the link so that I can test it?